# ReturnTrue if node is found

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to form new element if specific node is found, but if that specific node is present several times i need to form only one element, My code is forming the aifound  element twice.

```xml
<root>
  <ai>
    <i></i>
  </ai>
  <ai>
    <i></i>
  </ai>
</root>
```

output xml

```xml
    <root>
    <ai>
    <i></i>
    </ai>
    <ai>
    <i></i>
    </ai>
    <aifound>True</aifound>
    </root>
```

My xslt

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ai">    
    <aifound>True</aifound>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear whether you want to add `aifound` if there are no `ai`s at all. The following xslt adds `aifound` only if `ai`s exist.

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:if test="//ai">
                <aifound>True</aifound>    
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <aifound>
            <xsl:value-of select="boolean(ai)"/>
        </aifound>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```